# How to access .Net DLL in Java/JSP

Tags: java, .net, dll

I have dotnet BotDetect.dll and I need to use this in Java/JSP to implement and validate captcha on JSP page.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many JNI frameworks that do this, there's for example [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/).

In my experience, using JNI always leads to memory leaks and undiscoverable bugs, so if you can, try migrating your captcha code to Java code. If this is not possible, then use a JNI framework, but *be careful*.